# Talend open studio for data integration: how to convert fields of a record in xml and store it in a field of the same record

Tags: xml, postgresql, etl, talend

Hopefully someone can help, because I'm struggling for days with the same problem.

I have to read some csv data in a postgres DB with talend open studio for data integration. So far so good, but I'm struggling with one problem. For each row in the csv file, I have to save a field in the db that contains a xml view of that row e.g.:

```
 <tablename><column1>value_of_column_one</column1><column2>value_of_column2</column2>...</tablename>).
```

The tag `<tablename>` is the same for each row.

A solution that works is to concatenate the values of the different fields of a row and manually concatenate the xml tags:

```
"<tablename>"+"<column1>"value+"</column1>"....
```

But this isn't a nice solution. I was hoping that there was a clever solution with XML building blocks of Talend.

So I tried solutions with tXMLmap and tWriteXMLField, but the problem is that these blocks generate combinations for each record in the db with each row in the XML file. So not only the XML structure of record 1 is stored in the field of record 1, but also the XML structure of record 2 is stored in the field of record 1, and so on ...

The only thing I want to do is store the XML structure of record 1 in a field of record one, and store the field structure of record 2 in the field of record 2, ...

Can someone show me the right way to do this. It will be much appreciated.

Kind regards

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create xml file for a set of fields in Talend. You need not use any components for that. Rather, In schema dialogue box of the DB connection or an input file, there is an icon at the bottom that helps to save the schema in xml format.

Basically, you can upload an existing schema to Talend tool by clicking a similar icon, instead of manually writing all the fields and their parameters.